# I am not able to send multiple checkbox values in PHP mail function

Tags: php, html, email

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="expertform.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="eaid" value="" class="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First and Last Name</label>
        <input type="input" id="flname" name="flname" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="xemail" name="xemail" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Website</label>
        <input type="input" id="website" name="website" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <h4>Your Area(s) of Expertise </h4>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Fitness/Wellness"> Fitness/Wellness
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Relationship"> Relationship
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Self-Improvement/ Self-Empowerment"> Self-Improvement/ Self-Empowerment
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Entrepreneurism"> Entrepreneurism
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Money Management"> Money Management
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Travel/Lifestyle Advice"> Travel/Lifestyle Advice
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Others"> Others
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label ><b>Approximately how many clients/readers/followers do you have, combined? </b> </label>
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="approxclient" name="approxclient"></textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Any other thought and comments on the platform</b></label>
        <textarea  id="comments" name="comments" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>

    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my PHP function to send the mail. It is not able to send checkbox value to mail but everything else is working fine.

```
if(!preg_match("/http/i", $_POST['approxclient']) && $_POST['eaid'] == '' && !$_POST['flname'] == '' && !$_POST['xemail'] == '' ) {

    $my_email88 = 'email@example.org' . ', '; // note the comma
    $subject = "INTERESTED IN PARTNERING";

    // Use the submitters email if they supplied one (and it isn't trying to hack your form).
    // Otherwise send from your email address.
    if( $_POST['email'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email']) ) {
        $headers = "From: $_POST[email]\n";
    } else {
        $headers = "From: $my_email88\n";
    }

    //$headers = $headers . "Bcc: put email id here \n";

    // prepare a "pretty" version of the message
    $message = $message . "Name and Last Name: " . $_POST['flname'] .  "\n";    //" " . $_POST['lname'] .
    $message = $message . "Email: " . $_POST['xemail'] . "\n";
    $message = $message . "Website. " . $_POST['website'] . "\n";
    $message = $message . "Your Area(s) of Expertise"."\n";
    $services = 'None';

    if(isset($_POST['services']) && is_array($_POST['services']) && count($_POST['services']) > 0){
        $selectedServices = implode(', ', $_POST['services']);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can prefer send multiple checkbox value in PHP mail function.

Comment: yes i am trying to do that with above code but not able to send checkbox value and other field are working fine

Comment: What is input type "input"? Is that a your real email in the code (suggest removing it). Your best way of debugging this is to `var_dump($_POST)` in your mail function and compare what you see with what you're expecting to see.

Comment: where is the actual sending of the mail? do you actually append the selected services to your mail text?

Comment: Be very *very* careful about using raw `$_POST` data directly in your email content, especially in headers -- a malicious user could easily post data to your form that allows them to break your email formatting and use it for sending spam. You can avoid issues like this by using a properly written mailing library like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer instead of the raw `mail()` function. You will still need to be careful of `$_POST` vars in your body text, but these libs will prevent hackers from post data to break your mail headers to send spam. (and they'll make your mail code neater too as a bonus)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that is working perfectly

```
 $services = 'None';
 if(!empty($_POST['services']) && is_array($_POST['services'])){
     $message = $message .  implode(', ', $_POST['services']). "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add following to your code,

```
$message = $message . "Your Area(s) of Expertise"."\n";

if(isset($_POST['services']) && is_array($_POST['services']) && count($_POST['services']) > 0){
    $selectedServices = implode(', ', $_POST['services']);
    foreach($selectedServices as $ss)
    {
    $message = $message.$ss;
    } 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense - you collapse the `$_POST['services']` array into a string and then try to loop over it, which will probably work because it's indexing the string like an array of characters, but it's weird and unhelpful like that. Just `$message .= $selectedServices` should do the trick.

Comment: $message .= $selectedServices didn't wotk because you cant write the array directly without its index value.

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta after implode, there is no array. it's just a string after that.

Comment: I added this code on my file but not sending checkbox value in email